# Translating and renaming attributes from one layer to another

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have two shapefiles, one that contains data from our Corporate GIS system and another that I want to import into a software model.

I want to select a subset of the Corporate GIS data (for instance all reservoirs in a given area) and create a new SHP for use in a model. I want to utilise only a subset of the attributes and rename them to match the schema for the model. I am happy to recreate the model SHP every time.

At present, I export it into Excel, and manually manipulate the data. However, I would like to ultimately do this step in a Process Model in QGIS so I can automate it. Is this possible to do? I tried joins but to no success.

For example, I would use an expression to Filter the Corporate SHP to the records I want. Then translate the fields and selection into a new SHP

- Corporate SHP (AssetID) -> Skip
- Corporate SHP (Name) - > Model SHP (ID)
- Corporate SHP (Value) -> Skip
- Corporate SHP (Level) -> Model SHP (RL)
- Corporate SHP (Easting) -> Model SHP (X)
- Coprorate SHP (Northing) -> Model SHP (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to select some fields, rename them and export the data to a new file. This task can be performed using this QGIS tools:

1. [Refactor fields](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields)
2. [Extract selected features](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#extract-selected-features)
3. [Drop field(s)](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#drop-field-s)